# How to set environment for Go on windows and build project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, go, visual-studio-2022

[Error environment golang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGMFl.png)

[Environment setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhwKV.png)

I can't run project in Visual Studio 2022 I found this problem "he system cannot find the path specified. cannot find package "main.go" in any of"

Comment: [Go - Environment Setup](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/go/go_environment.htm#:~:text=Installation%20on%20Windows,the%20change%20to%20take%20effect.)

Comment: I use [golang-tools-install-script](https://github.com/canha/golang-tools-install-script) for the installation and removal of golang. Very effective and easy to use.

Comment: Also you should not set the path of `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` to your project path.